# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed in Graph execution

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, coreml, coremltools

Hey I am trying to convert my Keras model to CoreML but i keep getting this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a tf.Tensor as 
a Python bool is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this 
function with @tf.function.
```

Here is my code:

```
import keras
import coremltools
import tensorflow as tf

model = keras.models.load_model('machine.h5')

print(model.input)
print(model.input_shape)
print(model.output)

model= coremltools.converters.keras.convert(
'machine.h5', input_name_shape_dict={'embedding_input:0': (None, 24)},
output_names=['dense_2/Sigmoid:0'])

model.save('xcodeModel.mlmodel')
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Hopefully there is an answer to this!

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is from the Tensorflow and the Keras version you are using. Kindly downgrade tensorflow to version '1.14.0' and Keras to version '2.2.4' maybe it will solve the problem.